Function returning "None"
I wrote the short program below while practising how to use a custom function.
def square(num):
    square==(num**2) 
    print(square(10))
    return 

I was expecting that when I call the function:
print(square(10))

it should give me 100 but it just returns a blank screen or sometimes None.

try calling the function from outside the function, so after the return print the line you want calling the square function.

Your current code has several issues:
def square(num):
    square == num ** 2
    print(square(10))
    return


You should call your square function from outside of it; otherwise, it will keep calling itself recursively.
When assigning a variable, use =. However, you've used == instead, which is a binary operator.
The function currently returns nothing (None) instead of returning the computed result.

To fix these problems, use this code:
def square(num):
    result = num ** 2
    return result

# Call the func and print its result
print(square(10)) # Output: 100


You fixed the problem. Thank you for the prompt response.

@techgolimited you're welcome!
